Is "ResponseCache" middleware enabled by default?
According to this page, I should enable the response caching middleware to use the ResponseCache attribute on endpoints.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddResponseCaching(); // <--- here

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// UseCors must be called before UseResponseCaching
//app.UseCors();

app.UseResponseCaching(); // <--- here

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I only added the ResponseCache attribute to my controller endpoints and forgot to add the above lines to enable and configure the response caching middleware. However, the endpoints did return the correct cache configuration.
Did I misunderstood the text in the page or this feature is enabled by default now?

The [ResponseCache] attribute is for HTTP caching (AKA response caching), and not for server-side caching. This attribute appends response caching related headers to the response, which will tell browsers to cache the response and not make another HTTP request next time the same URL gets requested. You don't need the middleware to use the [ResponseCache] attribute. In this scenario, if a response is already cached, no request gets made to the server.
In contrast, server-side caching is done to store/cache responses on the server and to serve responses from the cache. The response caching middleware is used for server-side caching (AddResponseCaching()). In this scenario, a network request will be made, and the server will return a response from the cache without needing to recalculate a response (if a response is already cached).
Docs for HTTP caching/response caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Docs for server-side caching: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-8.0
